# Is there annotation for mark a visibility variable in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, view, annotations

`View.VISIBLE` and similar static visibility variables have data type as `int`, and me need forbid make values of this variables as "0", "1" etc. This variable should take only `View.VISIBLE` and similar values. For example:

```
    data class State(
        @SomeAnnotation val buttonVisibility: Int  
    )

    val state = State(0) // Compilation error
    val state = State(View.GONE) // Okay
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that android.view.View.Visibility is marked with @hide and cannot be used in code probably the only solution is to create custom enum like

```
enum class Visibility(val value: Int) {
    VISIBLE(View.VISIBLE), 
    INVISIBLE(View.INVISIBLE), 
    GONE(View.GONE)
}
```

And use it in State class

```
data class State(val buttonVisibility: Visibility)
```

Comment: I'm cannot import this annotation. Compiler displaying error.

`import android.view.View.Visibility // Unresolved reference: Visibility`

Comment: Ah, yes, it is marked with "@hide" annotation, so cannot be used. Updated the answer.